# C#-SQL to C#-MongoDB conversion. No DataAdapter for C#-MongoDB?

Tags: c#, sql, mongodb, winforms, dataadapter

I have been trying to look for DataAdapter for MongoDB for C# informs application but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Is there even such a thing?
I am working on a Login Page where a user enters their username and password and it checks in the database whether such username and password exist or not.

Below is the SQL C# code for creating connection and checking if the username and password exist:

```
SqlConnection sql_con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source= xxxxxx");

string query = "SELECT * FROM SignUp WHERE Username = '" + Username_TextBox.Text.Trim() + "' AND Password = '" + Password_TextBox.Text.Trim() + "'";            

SqlDataAdapter sql_da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sql_con);

DataTable sql_dt = new DataTable();

sql_da.Fill(sql_dt);

if (sql_dt.Rows.Count == 1 && Username_TextBox.Text.Substring(0,4) == "WRDN")
{
    //some code
}
```

I found this little snippet but it has SQL written in it and the MongoDBConnection and MongoDBDataAdapter do not exist.

```
string connectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=27017;";

using (MongoDBConnection connection = new MongoDBConnection(connectionString))
{
    MongoDBDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MongoDBDataAdapter("SELECT City, CompanyName FROM Customers", connection);

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    dataAdapter.Fill(table);

    Console.WriteLine("Contents of Customers.");

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", row["City"], row["CompanyName"]);
    }
}
```

How is this all actually achieved using MongoDB and C#?

Comment: The vendor provides documentation for their C# driver: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/csharp  There are probably also drivers/libraries available that you can find online, perhaps in NuGet.  As for the code snippet that you found, you might try checking where you found it for more information.  If they don't have any more information, it could very well be a dead end.  (Side note: Your original SQL code is wide open to SQL injection.  That's worth fixing both in SQL and in MongoDB.)

Comment: No information was provided where I found this little snippet. Did some research and found out a way to do it. As for SQL injection, what do you mean and what should I do to avoid it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found this little package that allows you to use standard drivers to access data from a MongoDB database.

**Step 1:** Open **Visual Studio > Tools > Manage NuGet Packages** and search for **CData ADO.NET Provider for MongoDB 2019**.

**Step 2:** Download and install it.

**Step 3:** You'll be prompted to download a key for it. Click **OK** on the pop-up and your browser will open up and you'll be directed to the download page for it. Click on the **Download Trial Key** button. Once downloaded, install the key.

**Step 4:** Once it's all done, head back to your C# form and insert

```
using System.Data.CData.MongoDB;
```

Now, you can use the **MongoDBDataAdapter** and **MongoDBConnection** to access the data from your MongoDB database.